# SQL command error "syntax to use near '0, `id_customer` int(10) NOT NUL at line 5........."

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQl, i am getting this error, any help will be appreciated.

Exception thrown by module g_autoassignvip on reset. Error when resetting module g_autoassignvip. You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, `id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL, `updatevip_' at line 5

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `soft_g_autoassignvip` (
            `id_g_autoassignvip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `vipno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `id_number` int(10) NULL,
            `renewal_status` int(11) 0,
            `id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
            `updatevip_date` date NOT NULL,
            `next_update` date NOT NULL,
            `join_date` date NOT NULL,
            `expire_date` date NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id_g_autoassignvip`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
```

Comment: I have no idea what the zero at the end of `renewal_status int(11) 0,` is trying to achieve. Nor does the database system

Comment: Maybe you meant default 0 like `renewal_status  int(11)  not null default 0` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `0` after `renewal_status int(11)`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `soft_g_autoassignvip` (
            `id_g_autoassignvip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `vipno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `id_number` int(10) NULL,
            `renewal_status` int(11) ,
            `id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
            `updatevip_date` date NOT NULL,
            `next_update` date NOT NULL,
            `join_date` date NOT NULL,
            `expire_date` date NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id_g_autoassignvip`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
```

Or if you want `0` as default value for `renewal_status` then try this one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `soft_g_autoassignvip` (
            `id_g_autoassignvip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `vipno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `id_number` int(10) NULL,
            `renewal_status` int(11) default 0,
            `id_customer` int(10) NOT NULL,
            `updatevip_date` date NOT NULL,
            `next_update` date NOT NULL,
            `join_date` date NOT NULL,
            `expire_date` date NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id_g_autoassignvip`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT
```

Comment: Or maybe he was thinking about `default 0 `

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur  
JazakALLAH brother for correcting it.

Comment: @RevolBegins you are most welcome brother. Best wishes.

Comment: @kazi Sorry just did it